# Materialize divier with text in the middle

Tags: css, html, materialize

Hi to all out there familiar with materialize.
I would like to make the divider:

```
<div class="divider"></div>
```

Look similar to this:
[image: Text divider]

It is basically the divier with text in the middle.
Does anyone have a solution? If not with material divier even with other html and css would be fine

Thanks

Comment: One solution is using `position: absolute` for 'Or' and position it in middle of the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am a fan of wrapping the text with a `div` with a fixed height. Then `position: relative` the text inside the `div`. See the snippet below.

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: black;
  height: 1px;
  margin: 32px 0 0;
  text-align: center;
}

span {
  position: relative;
  top: -8px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  font-weight: 500;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #000000;
  background: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <span>OR</span>
</div>
```